# UI font scaling messed up in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I was playing around with some of the font scaling features in Windows 7, and I seem to have broken something. To be precise, I increased the font scale to 150%, and then put it back to 100% (which is what it was before I started messing around). Now my window contents are scaled correctly, but my UI elements are too small.

Here are some pics to show what's going on.

[image]

[image]

The first screenshot is from Firefox, the second is Explorer. In both, the window contents are fine, but the text in the menu bar, tabs and bookmarks is too small. This is happening with every program I use, except for Office 2013.

My monitor is a Dell 24" 1920x1200, running in native resolution.

Anyone know what's going on, and how I can fix this?

Comment: I guess you allready restarted the computer?

Comment: @IvanViktorovic Yes, a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by resetting the desktop theme to one of the default themes supplied by Windows. This is detailed at [Chris Nahr's blog,](http://kynosarges.org/WindowsDpi.html#WrongSize) among other places.

> Sometimes, after changing DPI settings, you may notice certain system fonts that are either too big or too small for your new settings. The likely cause is that you were using a custom desktop theme based on your old DPI settings. Windows does not dare scale the fonts of custom themes.
>
> If you actually did create a custom desktop theme and want to retain it, you’ll have to edit the fonts yourself to adapt them to your new DPI settings. However, Windows has an annoying habit of “helpfully” creating custom themes all by itself, for whatever reason. So if you never wanted a custom desktop theme to begin with, delete it and revert to a standard theme.
>
> On Windows 7/8, open the Control Panel, choose “Appearance and Personalization” and then “Personalization”. If you see a selected entry in the “My Themes” row at the top, that means Windows is using a custom theme which is messing with your system font scaling. Select a standard theme instead, e.g. the first entry under “Aero Themes” (Windows 7) or “Windows Default Themes” (Windows 8), and delete the unwanted “My Themes” entry. All system fonts should now appear correctly.